# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Steps to move existing RDS from db.t1.micro to db.t2.small

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rds

I'm new to AWS and having a web server environment on elastic beanstalk with EC2 (t1.micro) with RDS (db.t1.micro). Now the db.t1.micro instance is deprecated, no more new instance can be created and no support in near future.

I would be helpful if anybody refers me steps to do create the t2 clone of the machine and switch over (Or) how to handle the depreciation of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change Instance Type: You can change the Instance type by following the AWS documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.ec2.html)
2. Next, Creating RDS instance in the Elastic Beanstalk environment is not ideal for production environments, because the lifecycle of the database instance is tied to the lifecycle of your application's environment. Hence it is always recommended to create RDS instance outside of the Elastic Beanstalk environment and configure your Elastic Beanstalk application to connect it on launch, which will provide the benefits of performing blue/green deployments, and tear down your Beanstalk environment without affecting the database instance. Refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html?icmpid=docs_elasticbeanstalk_console) to know more information.

For now, if you would like to modify the RDS instance type, you can do so by going to the RDS section in Configuration tab.

Comment: 1. The t1 instances are not in VPC, So Elastic Beanstalk is not allowing to change the instance type to t2 (which will run only on VPC).

Comment: For point #2: Instead of breaking the Elastic Beanstalk environment, I tried to replicate the Elastic Beanstalk and switch over. Since the t1 machines on the Elastic Beanstalk, it will no allow cloning the environment. I have also tried to create a new Elastic Beanstalk environment with RDS, that RDS instance with the snapshot of the existing Elastic Beanstalk db.t1 environment. But the app deploy fails with the SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out with RDS.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new Elastic Beanstalk environment with the source of the "db.t1.micro" snapshot, within the VPC. This helped me to launch the clone. Once this is done I have to swap the cname with the t1 and t2 setup. The new instance is up and running with t2 configuration.